Invoke function on mouse over with framer motion
I'm trying to recreate the following codepen with framer motion:
https://codepen.io/Hyperplexed/pen/rNrJgrd?editors=0010
It doesn't animate, and I think the ref is not used by the function or framer motion.
Here's what I've tried:
import { FC, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";


const ForwardRefTypography = forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => (
    <Typography {...props} ref={ref} />
));

const TypographyMotion = motion.create(ForwardRefTypography);


const TestComponent: FC = () => {
    const ref = useRef<any>(null);
    const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    const [text, setText] = useState("HYPERPLEXED");
    const [iteration, setIteration] = useState(0);
    const dataValue = "HYPERPLEXED";

    const handleMouseMove = (e: any) => {
        let interval: any = null;
        setIteration(0);
        clearInterval(interval);

        interval = setInterval(() => {
            setText(prevText =>
                prevText.split("").map((letter, index) => {
                    if (index < iteration) {
                        return dataValue[index];
                    }
                    return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)];
                }
                ).join("")
            );

            if (iteration >= dataValue.length) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }

            setIteration(prev => prev + 1 / 3);
        }, 30);
    };


    return (
        <TypographyMotion ref={ref} onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>
            { text }
        </TypographyMotion>
    );
}

